# How to configure druid properly to fire a periodic kill task

Tags: druid

I have been trying to get druid to fire a kill task periodically to clean up unused segments.

These are the configuration variables responsible for it

```
druid.coordinator.kill.on=true
druid.coordinator.kill.period=PT45M
druid.coordinator.kill.durationToRetain=PT45M
druid.coordinator.kill.maxSegments=10
```

From the above configuration my mental model is, once ingested data is marked unused, kill task will fire and delete the segments that are older that 45 mins while retaining 45 mins worth of data. `period` and `durationToRetain` are the config vars that are confusing me, not quite sure how to leverage them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caveat for `druid.coordinator.kill.on=true` is that segments are deleted from whitelisted datasources. The whitelist is empty by default.
To populate the whitelist with all datasources, set `killAllDataSources` to `true`. Once I did that, the `kill` task fired as expected and deleted the segments from `s3 (COS)`. This was tested for Druid version 0.18.1.

Now, while the above configuration properties can be set when you build your image, the `killAllDataSources` needs to be set through an API. This can be set via the druid UI too. [image: Where to find coordinator ui]

When you click the option, a modal appears that has *Kill All Data Sources*. Click on *True* and you should see a kill task (Ingestion ---> Tasks below) firing in the interval specified. It would be really nice to have this as a part of *runtime.properties* or some sort of common configuration file that we can set the value in when build the druid image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a control outside the druid over the segments removal, then you must use an scheduled task which runs based on your desire interval and register kill-tasks in druid. It can increase your control over your segments, since when they go away, you cannot recover them. You can use this script to accompany you:

https://github.com/mostafatalebi/druid-kill-task

Answer (score -1):

Use crontab it works quite well for us.

Comment: The above configuration works well for us. It has been in production for three weeks now. I vetoed against crontab.